# How to authenticate google cloud SDK on a docker Ubuntu image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-sdk

I am a bit confused about how I can authenticate the gcloud sdk on a docker container. Right now, my docker file includes the following:

```
#Install the google SDK
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud
RUN tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
RUN /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

However, I am confused how I would authenticate? When I run `gcloud auth application-default login` on my machine, it opens a new tab in chrome which prompts me to login. How would I input my credentials on the docker container if it opens a new tab in google chrome in the container?

Answer (score 27):

You might consider using deb packages when setting up your docker container as it is done on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/%7E/dockerfile/).

That said you should NOT run `gcloud init` or `gcloud auth application-default login` or `gcloud auth login`... those are interactive commands which launch browser. To provide credentials to the container supply it with service account key file.

You can download one from cloud console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=YOUR_PROJECT or create it with `gcloud` command

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create
```

see [reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create).

Either way once you have the key file ADD it to your container and run

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=MY_KEY_FILE.json
```

You should be now set, but if you want to use it as Application Default Credentials (ADC), that is in the context of other libraries and tools, you need to set the following environment variable to point to the key file:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/the/path/to/MY_KEY_FILE.json
```

One thing to point out here is that `gcloud` tool does not use ADC, so later if you change your account to something else, for example via

```
gcloud config set core/account my_other_login@gmail.com
```

other tools and libraries will continue using old account via ADC key file but `gcloud` will now use different account.

Comment: The command has changed to `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=MY_KEY_FILE.json`

Comment: isn't a good practice to add json credentials to a container? I think google does not approve that practive. be carefull with this...

Comment: @LuisParada what other option remains if you can't add json credentials to a container?

Comment: @LuisParada I believe the concern is with baking the credentials into the _image_.

Comment: I would say the below answer is the correct one

Comment: Another option is workload identity federation. Wont need to create a key

Answer (score 26):

You can map your local Google SDK credentials into the image. [[Source]](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-test-google-cloud-services-locally-in-docker-d74196147841).

Begin by signing in using:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

Then add the following to your docker-compose.yaml:

```
volumes:
  - ~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud
```

Comment: if you dont want to share the entire `.config` directory, `~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud` should also work.