# Setting an active gcloud account in docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-ml, kubeflow

Currently i'm setting up a [Kubeflow Pipeline](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/pipelines-overview/) on GKE.
The goal is to start a trainingjob on the ML Engine and later on serve it on GKE.

The trainingjob gets launched in a Docker container. (Every step in a pipeline must be a container.)

I'm getting the following error when running the container:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

The docker containers gets credentials via service account as suggested in [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472882/how-to-authenticate-google-cloud-sdk-on-a-docker-ubuntu-image).

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.8.0-devel-gpu-py3

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q ca-certificates python-dev python-setuptools wget unzip git


# Components to run ML Engine job on cluster
RUN cd / && \
    wget -nv https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.zip && \
    unzip -qq google-cloud-sdk.zip -d tools && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk.zip && \
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false \
        --path-update=false --bash-completion=false \
        --disable-installation-options && \
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud -q components update \
        gcloud core gsutil && \
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set component_manager/disable_update_check true && \
    touch /tools/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/google.py

ENV PATH $PATH:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin

RUN mkdir /workdir

COPY . /workdir

RUN export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/workdir/ml6-sandbox-cdc8cb4bcae2.json

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/workdir/ml-engine/train.sh"]
```

The error finds place in train.sh where i'm submitting a trainingjob:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
    --runtime-version 1.8 \
    --python-version 3.5 \
    --module-name trainer.run_train \
    --package-path ./trainer \
    --region $REGION \
    --config=trainer/config.yaml \
    --stream-logs \
    -- \
    --data-dir $DATA_DIR \
    --version $VERSION
```

In my run_train.py, i'm getting the Google Application Credentials the following:

```
os.environ[
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/workdir/ml6-sandbox-cdc8cb4bcae2.json'
```

Train.sh works standalone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable when [using the client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application).

As you are using the `gcloud` CLI change this line:

`RUN export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/workdir/ml6-sandbox-cdc8cb4bcae2.json`

to

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account yourServiceAccount --key-file=/workdir/ml6-sandbox-cdc8cb4bcae2.json
```

This will log your service account as the the active account used by `gcloud`.

Also, this service account needs to be granted with the proper [roles](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/access-control).