# How can i access model artifacts on google ai platform (unified)?

Tags: gcloud, google-ai-platform

I want to be able to load data from within the model, but without having to deliver the data files with the container that the model is built upon,
i have used that command to upload the model to the platform:

```
gcloud beta ai models upload \
  --display-name=MODEL_NAME \
  --region=us-central1 \
  --container-image-uri=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/MODEL_URI \
  --container-predict-route=/predict \
  --container-health-route=/health \
  --container-ports=80  \
  --artifact-uri=gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_WHERE_DATA_IS
```

So, if in: gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_WHERE_DATA_IS there exist a file named foo.bar
i expect that i will be able to read it from within the code built by the docker as if it was local, is that correct?
because when trying to deploy the model i get that files (say: "foo.bar" that is in gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_WHERE_DATA_IS) can't be found

Answer (score 1):

Specifying  `--artifact-uri=gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_WHERE_DATA_IS` only makes the bucket available with the correct credentials from within the container that is running on the platform, you should read the env "AIP_STORAGE_URI" for the gcs path where a copy of the data is located and download from that uri the data that your model needs
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts

Bear in mind that you will also need to authenticate your account from within the container
[How to authenticate google cloud SDK on a docker Ubuntu image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472882/how-to-authenticate-google-cloud-sdk-on-a-docker-ubuntu-image)